# azure policy deny changes on resources with source:terraform tag

Tags: azure, terraform, tags, policy

I want to deniy changes on resources with the tag "source":"terraform" in the azure ui, because these resources will be managed with terraform and should not be changed in the ui.

1. question:
   Is a policy the right way to do that?
2. question:
   Why is my current policy not working?

> ```
> {
>   "mode": "All",
>   "policyRule": {
>     "if": {
>       "anyOf": [
>         {
>           "field": "tags['source']",
>           "exists": "true"
>         },
>         {
>           "field": "tags['source']",
>           "equals": "terraform"
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     "then": {
>       "effect": "deny"
>     }
>   },
>   "parameters": {}
> }
> ```

I added this policy to my subscription "test-subscription-123" and after that I changed a resource with the tag "source":"terraform" in that subscription in the azure ui and it was still possible.
But I want my policy to deny that.

3. question
   Will my policy (when its finally working) deny Terraform from changing my resources too? If yes, I need to adapt my policy I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> azure policy deny changes on resources with source:terraform tag

Here is the updated policy to **deny** changes on resources if the tag matched **"source":"terraform"** , it will **deny** all changes on the resource.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['source']",
              "exists": "true"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['source']",
              "equals": "terraform"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

The policy is preventing changes when attempting to modify the `VM size`.

**Output:**

[image]

The policy **denies** the creation of an address space in the **virtual network** when attempting to create one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented your policy on my side and create a virtual machine and changed the size, but unfortunately the policy did not prevent this. I double checked, the policy and my vm are in the same resource group. does your policy prevent you from editing tags?

Comment: Yes,Please check the policy compliance status, whether the policy has started or not, and also check the policy assignment scope to see where the policy was assigned.

Comment: thanks for your help, I forgot to assign the policy :)